# Unknown identifier при использование left join

Tags: sql, join, clickhouse

Возникает ошибка при запросе с Clickhouse

> Code: 47, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Unknown identifier: cohort_month there are columns: user_id, event_date, 'month', date_trunc('month', event_date), toDate(date_trunc('month', event_date)): While processing user_id, dateDiff('month', toDate(date_trunc('month', event_date)), cohort_month) (version 21.3.7.62 (official build))

```
select 
       A.device_id,
       dateDiff('month', toDate(date_trunc('month', A.event_date)), C.cohort_month)
from logs.track A
         left join ( select toDate(date_trunc('month', U.event_date)) as cohort_month,
                            device_id
                     from logs.track U
                     order by 1, 2) C
        ON A.device_id = C.device_id
group by A.device_id, A.event_date;
```

Подзапрос отдельно выполняется, ни как не пойму почему не видит **cohort_month**

```
select toDate(date_trunc('month', U.event_date)) as cohort_month,
       device_id
from logs.track U
order by 1, 2
```

Comment: Order в join'е зачем?

Comment: @РустамАлиев забыл убрать(

Comment: Заработало после этого или нет?

Comment: @РустамАлиев нет, не работает

Comment: Не понимаю, почему текст сообщения об ошибке (фрагмент кода в нём) и текст запроса не совпадают. Куда подевались алиасы таблиц?

Comment: @Akina не совсем понял вас

Comment: В запросе есть алиас таблицы `C.cohort_month`, а в тексте сообщения об ошибке только имя поля `cohort_month`  - почему?

Comment: @Akina Честно не знаю, так выдает ошибку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно было в **group by** делать группировку не по `A.event_date`, а по  `dateDiff('month', toDate(date_trunc('month', A.event_date)), C.cohort_month)` ну или доавить alias к `dateDiff('month', toDate(date_trunc('month', A.event_date)), C.cohort_month) month_number` и его указывать в **group by**